# How can I access blocked websites in firefox?

Tags: browser

In the recent waves of blocking websites in different countries, India also started doing it. Recently India blocked some regional websites. So I want to know is there any way to bypass the blocking and visit those websites in Firefox? Is there any firefox add on  for this?

Comment: why not try with proxy sites

Comment: There is a browser based on Firefox design to do this specifically.  I would research that browser and use that.  Involves no technical skill to do so.  Using a proxy does require some degree of technical skill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [anonymox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/anonymox/) addon which will help you to surf beyond limits ,you can use it to surf blocked websites which were blocked at your country